# Can't load resource for Icon

Tags: java, image, icons, jbutton, getresource

I'm setting up a simple GUIand I got stuck trying to loading an image for a button.

```
public class Client extends JFrame{

    private JTextField field;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton send;
    private Socket socket;

    Client(){
        super("Messenger");
        try {
            socket=new Socket("localhost",65535);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("can't estabilish connection");
            return;
        }
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label=new JLabel("insert text here");
        add(label);
        field=new JTextField(20);
        add(field);
        ImageIcon ico=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/richard.png"));
        send=new JButton("send",ico);
        send.setFocusPainted(false);
        add(send);
        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            OutputStream out=socket.getOutputStream();
                            String s=field.getText();
                            if (s.equals(".")) {
                                out.write(s.getBytes());
                                socket.close();
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                            out.write((s+"\n").getBytes());
                            field.setText("");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
        pack();
        setLocation(500, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client();
    }

}
```

it's a simple client for a messanging app, but I can't get the image to show on the button. I'm using `getResource()` instead of the ImageIcon constructor because it wasn't showing in the Jar if I used that.
So what am I doing wrong?? it gives me a NullPointerException no matter how I write the URL. The image is under a "res" folder in my project..

this is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Client.<init>(Client.java:27)
    at Client.main(Client.java:58)
```

it originates (as expected) in the ImageIcon constructor..

Comment: Try to remove `res/`. To be sure of the location of your image, open your .jar file with 7Zip, for example.

Comment: To use resources, you have to use the path of the resource relative to the class files. Please inform us of this.

Comment: I tried everything , /res/richard.png, res/richard.png , richard.png...
the image is in the  res folder in the project's root folder..don't know what to do, or what I am doing wrong

Comment: The root folder might not work here. Move that folder so that it is a sub-directory of your class directory. If you're using Eclipse, drag and drop the res folder so that it is a branch off your class-path.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yeah! that nailed it!!
but why is it so? I can't find my way in the intricacies of file paths...

Comment: now it works in Eclipse,but I can't export the Jar file... the res folder seems just missing..

Comment: When you export you have to tell Eclipse to include resources. You did drag the file into the src directory, right?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels   I found it.. I put the res folder under source folder (where I keep my java source files) and then the path seems to work..and then I can export the file and retain the res folder and therefore the path to it..right?

Answer (score 0):

From [java.lang.Class#getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) API documenation:

> an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name
>   using this algorithm:
>
> If the name **begins with a '/'** ('\u002f'), then **the absolute name** of
>   the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'. **Otherwise**,
>   the absolute name is of the following form: **modified_package_name/name**
>   Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object
>   with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

If your image is under "res" folder (under project root) you need a slash and the path should look like:

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/richard.png"));
```